# How to traverse tree for making binary code from a HuffmanTree?

Tags: python, tree, compression, huffman-code

I'm trying to make binary code from a Huffman tree. I am stuck at tree traversal. To traverse tree and print code for every character frequency, I've written following code.

```
def printCode(node,prefix=""):
    if node.left:
        prefix = prefix+"0"
        printCode(node.left,prefix)
    elif node.right:
        prefix = prefix+"1"
        printCode(node.right,prefix)
    elif node.internal ==False:
        print(node.data,prefix)
        printCode(node,prefix="") #need change
```

Here is the necessary explanation:
If a node is not an internal node(node.internal=False) then it is a leaf, and at this point of traversal I'm printing the code with character frequencies. But i'm unable to go back to the previous internal node and continue with another branch of tree that has not been traversed yet. So this code is ended with only returning binary code for the first leaf of the tree.

The every node of tree is created with following code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data,internal=False):
        self.data = data  #frequency of a char
        self.internal = internal

        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `node.internal`?

Comment: Do you only want to print the leaves?

Comment: @SPYBUG96 if node.internal == True then it is a leaf, and at this point i'm gonna print the code for this leaf. I want to print leaves and corresponding binary code.

Comment: Cool, then my answer below should be solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your logic is the use of the `elif`

```
def printCode(node):
    if node.left:
        node.left.prefix = node.prefix+"0"
        printCode(node.left)

    if node.right:
        node.right.prefix = node.prefix+"1"
        printCode(node.right)

    if node.internal == False:
        print(node.data,node.prefix)
```

This way it will traverse the left side of the tree until it reaches a leaf, when it reaches a leaf it will print the node data. At this point in the code it goes back to the last recursive call (the node before the leaf) and it will go to the right node, if this right node is a leaf it will print out its node information, then it will go back to the last recursive call

Let me know if you need a better explanation, or if there was a misunderstanding and this doesn't do what you want it to

UPDATE:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data,internal=False):
        self.data = data  #frequency of a char
        self.internal = internal

        self.left = None
        self.right = None

        #Add a prefix to your nodes, so each node keeps track of its own prefix
        self.prefix = ""
```

Comment: Now the program has reached every leaves, but generating wrong binary code.

Comment: i'm sorry. Now you can't pass two parameters in printCode() as you've done in the _if_ _condition_. Though I've solved it, but now it is giving null. Prefix char(0 or 1) is not adding. May be you cant help me clearly if you look into my full code. Here is my gist:
https://gist.github.com/ipritom/e0b9867f14105d1c92cd49e5e6472fd9

Comment: i've solved this problem. I've updated the prefix in the _if_ _condition as node.prefix = node.prefix+"1". Thank You for helping me to find the solution.

Comment: @exiled Glad to help!